# Why does the Lubuntu minimum install say that it requires 10.7 GB of available drive space?

Tags: 11.04, xubuntu, lubuntu, ubuntu-minimal, dell-mini-9

I have a 4GB Dell Mini 9. I used UnetBootin following the instructions at [pendrivelinux.com](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/using-unetbootin-to-create-a-linux-usb-from-linux/).

I have tried Xubuntu minimal install, Lubuntu minimal install, and vanilla Lubuntu, and all result in the same issue:

The second screen of the install 'Preparing to install Ubuntu' says 'for best results, please ensure that this computer has at least 10.7 GB available drive space'.

Am I doing something wrong? The system requirements for these OSes are much lower than 10.7GB.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The minimal size is only recommendation -- if you want you can change it.

In LiveCD environment (before running installation) open terminal and run

`gksudo leafpad /usr/lib/ubiquity/plugins/ubi-prepare.py`

at line 303, there's variable `size` and at line `310` you'll find this

`min_disk_size = size * 2`

just change the number `2` for adjustment (now the minimal size is 5 GB * 2, I've replaced it with `0.8`), save the file and run Installator again.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Believe you are seeing a glitch in the installer, as they usually require 4.0GB. You can ignore that recommendation and install as normal.

Comment: except that the 'next' button is greyed out and inactive