# Change the list of applications to install in the LiveCD environment?

Tags: 11.10, installation, lubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to customize live Ubuntu CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-live-ubuntu-cd)

[Change the min_disk_size answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58442/why-does-the-lubuntu-minimum-install-say-that-it-requires-10-7-gb-of-available-d/58449#58449) to **Why does the Lubuntu minimum install say that it requires 10.7 GB of available drive space?** describes:

> In LiveCD environment...

Is it also possible to delete items from the application to be installed from the LiveCD environment? How?

Answer (score 0):

W.,

as described in your link this is a **suggestion**.

Using an alternate CD you can instal a minimal system even without window manager and then install only the applications you really need.

Greetings from Switzerland, Michael

Answer (score 0):

Try Lubuntu Slim 10.04 LTS from http://ubuntu-fr.org.

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove items which have to be installed on startup from a Canonical supplied CD/DVD/USB Stick but if u want, u can create a [Customised Live CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization) if u want, here is the link: 
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization 
Or if you want to install the packages by yourself, you could try [Ubuntu Server](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server/download): 
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server/download